# when i do `npm install` after create `npx create-react-app my-app` than its gives me error when i launch application `npm start`

Tags: reactjs, npm, create-react-app, npm-install, npm-start

```
Severity: moderate
Starting the development server...

Error: error:0308010C:digital envelope routines::unsupported
    at new Hash (node:internal/crypto/hash:71:19)
    at Object.createHash (node:crypto:133:10)
    at module.exports (D:\extras\meet up app with react\meet-up\node_modules\webpack\lib\util\createHash.js:90:53)
    at NormalModule._initBuildHash (D:\extras\meet up app with react\meet-up\node_modules\webpack\lib\NormalModule.js:401:16)      
    at handleParseError (D:\extras\meet up app with react\meet-up\node_modules\webpack\lib\NormalModule.js:449:10)
    at D:\extras\meet up app with react\meet-up\node_modules\webpack\lib\NormalModule.js:481:5
    at D:\extras\meet up app with react\meet-up\node_modules\webpack\lib\NormalModule.js:342:12
    at D:\extras\meet up app with react\meet-up\node_modules\loader-runner\lib\LoaderRunner.js:373:3
    at iterateNormalLoaders (D:\extras\meet up app with react\meet-up\node_modules\loader-runner\lib\LoaderRunner.js:214:10)       
    at iterateNormalLoaders (D:\extras\meet up app with react\meet-up\node_modules\loader-runner\lib\LoaderRunner.js:221:10)       
    at D:\extras\meet up app with react\meet-up\node_modules\loader-runner\lib\LoaderRunner.js:236:3
    at runSyncOrAsync (D:\extras\meet up app with react\meet-up\node_modules\loader-runner\lib\LoaderRunner.js:130:11)
    at iterateNormalLoaders (D:\extras\meet up app with react\meet-up\node_modules\loader-runner\lib\LoaderRunner.js:232:2)        
    at Array.<anonymous> (D:\extras\meet up app with react\meet-up\node_modules\loader-runner\lib\LoaderRunner.js:205:4)
    at Storage.finished (D:\extras\meet up app with react\meet-up\node_modules\enhanced-resolve\lib\CachedInputFileSystem.js:55:16)
    at D:\extras\meet up app with react\meet-up\node_modules\enhanced-resolve\lib\CachedInputFileSystem.js:91:9
D:\extras\meet up app with react\meet-up\node_modules\react-scripts\scripts\start.js:19
  throw err;
  ^

Error: error:0308010C:digital envelope routines::unsupported
    at new Hash (node:internal/crypto/hash:71:19)
    at Object.createHash (node:crypto:133:10)
    at module.exports (D:\extras\meet up app with react\meet-up\node_modules\webpack\lib\util\createHash.js:90:53)
    at NormalModule._initBuildHash (D:\extras\meet up app with react\meet-up\node_modules\webpack\lib\NormalModule.js:401:16)
    at D:\extras\meet up app with react\meet-up\node_modules\webpack\lib\NormalModule.js:433:10
    at D:\extras\meet up app with react\meet-up\node_modules\webpack\lib\NormalModule.js:308:13
    at D:\extras\meet up app with react\meet-up\node_modules\loader-runner\lib\LoaderRunner.js:367:11
    at D:\extras\meet up app with react\meet-up\node_modules\loader-runner\lib\LoaderRunner.js:233:18
    at context.callback (D:\extras\meet up app with react\meet-up\node_modules\loader-runner\lib\LoaderRunner.js:111:13)     
    at D:\extras\meet up app with react\meet-up\node_modules\babel-loader\lib\index.js:51:103 {
  opensslErrorStack: [ 'error:03000086:digital envelope routines::initialization error' ],
  library: 'digital envelope routines',
  reason: 'unsupported',
  code: 'ERR_OSSL_EVP_UNSUPPORTED'
}
```

Node.js v18.10.0

i have tried for again intalling node_moduls and `npm audit fix --force`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Uninstall and reinstall react-scripts

1. open the terminal and run `npm uninstall react-scripts`
2. run `npm install react-scripts`

Manually change the react script version

1. go to your `package.json` and change the `react-script` version to `5.0.2`
2. delete the `node_modules` folder by running `rm –rf node_modules`
3. delete the `package.lock.json` file by running `rm –rf package.lock.json`
4. run `npm install`